# Subsonic 3.0.0.4 views not working

Tags: sql-server, view, subsonic3

I went over to the subsonic website and downloaded the version 3.0.0.4. My project setup went well without errors. I then added the following to access two views in my DB

```
const string TABLE_SQL=@"SELECT *
    FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
    UNION
    SELECT TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME, 'View' TABLE_TYPE
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS";
```

In Visual Studio 2010 I am seeing the views were generated, however when I do the following to test

```
MsgBox(Accounting.vwVendor.All().Count().ToString())
```

I get no data. If I run the same for other generated tables, it works fine. I do see the following in VS Immediate Window

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in SubSonic.Core.dll

Am I missing something for accessing SQL Server views via SubSonic?

**UPDATED: I changed the target framework from Framework 4.0 Client Profile to Framework 3.5 Client Profile, build the solution, changed back the target framework to 4.0, build the solution and it worked!**

Comment: SubSonic works in the Client Profile, your problem was something else - quite possibly it was the t4 templates needing regeneration, which may have been triggered when you switched the target framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modification you list is all that should be needed to access Views with SubSonic.  I have even tested it in a new project, and had no issues.

If you post more details about the exception (like the stack trace), perhaps something will stand out.